# Cannot understand behaviour of promises in javascript

Tags: javascript, promise

Code block 1 executes in 2 seconds.

Code block 2 executes in 4 seconds.

Can someone explain what is the difference between them ?

```js
// Code block 1

const one = new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve('one'), 2000));
const two = new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve('two'), 2000));

(async() => {
  console.log(await one);
  console.log(await two);
})();
```

```js
// Code block 2

const one = () => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve('one'), 2000));
const two = () => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve('two'), 2000));

(async() => {
  console.log(await one());
  console.log(await two());
})();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first code block, both Promises get initialized immediately (when `one` and `two` are declared - you have `one = new Promise` and `two = new Promise`), so they both resolve at the same time.

In the second code block, the Promises are only created once the function is called. Because `await` will essentially block an async function, in

```
console.log(await one());
console.log(await two());
```

in `await one()`, you're invoking `one`, creating a Promise, and waiting for it to resolve.

*Then*, after that Promise has resolved and its value has been logged, the `console.log(await two())` invokes the second function, *creating the Promise*, which resolves after a couple seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in a sense there is no difference between the Promises, it is all about when they are being invoked.

In the first block of code the two Promises are invoked immediately, at the point the lines of code are executed. This means the timer for Promise two (P2) is kicked of immediately after Promise one (P1). So in that example you await P1, after 2 seconds it's done and moves to checking checking if P2 has resolved. It basically has, because it to has been running for 2 seconds, so prints the result.

In this slight modification you can see I've changed the timer of P2 to be shorter than P1, however it will still print in order. Inside of your closure your code is held up waiting for P1 to resolve, before it moves on to check P2, once it does move on, it will have already resolved and immediately execute the resolution callback printing the result.

```
const one = new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve('one'), 2000));
const two = new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve('two'), 1000));

(async () => {
    console.log(await one);
    console.log(await two);
})();
```

In the second block of code you are not initially invoking either Promise, but assigning a function the variables one & two - so neither timer is started initially. The first console.log invokes the first lambda function (P1) and awaits the response (which takes 2 seconds), then moves onto the next line and invokes 'two' which starts and awaits 2 seconds for a response.

It is important to remember that although the code inside of the closure you created is effectively held up and awaiting the resolution of the Promises, the program execution will continue outside of the closure. In the code below, you will see the message printed immediately, then the 'one' & 'two', two and four seconds later

```
const one = () => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve('one'), 2000));
const two = () => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve('two'), 2000));

(async () => {
    console.log(await one());
    console.log(await two());
})();
console.log ('Promises have been invoked: do other stuff while waiting');
```